# insert file size into database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm uploading the file and the size keep it 0 on database [image]

```
$djenjang_capaian = $this->session->userdata('djenjang_capaian');
        $pengirim = $this->session->userdata('pengirim');
        
        $path = FCPATH. "/upload/document/capaian/$pengirim";
        
        if(!is_dir($path))
        {
            mkdir($path,0777,TRUE);
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|pdf|xlsx|xls|doc|docx|zip|rar';
        $config['max_size'] = "2048";
        $file_name = "dok-cpn-" . rand(100, 999) . uniqid();
        $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('dokumen_file');
        $dokumen = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $dokumen_file = $dokumen;
        $ukuran_file = $dokumen_file['size'];
        $data = array(
            'dokumen_file' => $dokumen_file,
            'ukuran_file' => $ukuran_file
        );
        if ($this->db->insert($djenjang_capaian, $data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", " Data berhasil ditambahkan!");
            redirect('user/page/pemenuhan_dokumen');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", " Data gagal ditambahkan!");
            redirect('user/page/pemenuhan_dokumen');
        }
```

this code run well but keep insert 0 on ukuran_file field. How can I insert file size into database?? ...

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are oyu stuck? If you dump `$dokumen_file`, does it contain the size it shoul dcontain?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$ukuran_file = $dokumen_file['size'];
```

you have to use

```
$ukuran_file = $dokumen_file['file_size'];
```

Reference is here : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#class-reference